# Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - Importing Microsoft Access File

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just recently installed SQL Server 2014 and started following some tutorials but need some clarifications.

Problems:

1. When importing using the wizard I am advised to select "Microsoft Access" under "Data source" instead of "Microsoft Access(Microsoft Jet Database Engine)". The problem is there is no option for "Microsoft Access" when I try to make a selection.
2. I'm following a basic tutorial in which I concatenate two fields into one but the editor is warning me of syntax errors.

   ```
   SELECT 
      CONVERT(LastName + FirstName) AS "Emp Name"
   FROM EMPLOYEE
   ```

   Error:

   > Incorrect syntax near '+'

Comment: Well, your convert syntax is wrong, but why do you need to convert these?  They are already varchar.  Just remove the convert.

Comment: Thanks, I was just following a tutorial and they had me type it.

Comment: convert syntax is `convert(type, field)`.  So your case might go like this: `Convert(varchar(50), lastname) + convert(varchar(50), firstname) as [Emp Name]`.  But as noted, you dont need to convert.  So just concatenate.